# How Can I able to display following data is vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

My json response is

```
{"status": true, "data": {"basic": {"name": "haji", "dob": "2018-01-01", "gender": "male", "created_at": "2018-01-08T13:38:49.767Z", "firstname": "Ah", "lastname": "Sh", "userType": "Agent", "actor": 1, "username": "ashu", "contact": {"email": "ah@gmail.com", "phone": 863249517, "address": null}, "is_new": false, "is_email_verified": true, "is_phone_verified": true}, "wallet": {"amount": 144.0, "tds": 6.0}, "clan": null, "balance_lisitings": 48, "clan_status": false, "listings": [{"pid": 36, "name": "Labs", "website": "Labs", "category": {"name": "Education"}, "location": {"lat": 9.52766533190131, "lon":
76.8221354484558, "state": "Kerala", "country": "India", "district": {"id": 1, "name": "Kottayam"}, "city": {"id": 1, "name": "Kanjirappally"}, "place": {"id": 1, "name": "Koovappally"}}, "package": 0, "contact": {"email": "ah@gmail.com", "phone": 8986234851, "address": {"country": "India", "state": "Kerala", "name": "aloh", "pincode": 686895, "streetAddress": "Kottayam\nKanjirappally", "locality": "Koovappally", "city": "Koovappally"}}, "about": " IT company."}, {"pid": 37, "name": " Louis", "website": "ouis", "category": {"name": "Education"}, "location": {"lat": 10.0273434437709, "lon": 76.5288734436035, "state": "Kerala", "country": "India", "district": {"id": 1, "name": "Kottayam"}, "city": {"id": 1, "name": "Kanjirappally"}, "place": {"id": 1, "name": "Koovappally"}}, "package": 0, "contact": {"email": "soew988@gmail.com", "phone": 989756240, "address": {"country": "India", "state": "Kerala", "name": "allen45", "pincode": 686518, "streetAddress": "Sppally", "locality": "Koovappally", "city": "Koovappally"}}, "about": "fsdbgfnvb cvc"}], "total_listings": 2}}
```

========================================================================

My vue js script is

```
<script>
  new Vue({
  el: '#listings' ,
  data: {
     data: [],
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
            url: "https://",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (e) {

                    self.data = e.data;

            },
        });
    })
  },

})

</script>
```

My html code is

```
<div id="listings">
<h1>{{basic.name}}</h1>
<h2>{{basic.dob}}</h2>
like wise all data
</div>
```

Can anybody please help me to display the same. I am weak in js. This is the data I am getting I need to display the above data in vue js. I store all the data to a variable data[]. From it, how can I able to display the same?

Comment: Also in Vue.js 2.x `data` must be a function. `data ()  { return {  data: [] } }`,

Comment: sir, it is vue.js

Comment: You tagged [tag:vuejs2]

Comment: sorry sir,.....

Comment: The `data` of a `new Vue` does not have to be a function, only the `data` of a component.

Comment: i don;t understand sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you'll need is a [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) to keep things from rendering when there's no data.

You have a `data` variable and `basic` is inside it. As you have it, all the things you want to include are inside it, so you will have a lot of things like `data.basic.name`.

```js
const e = {
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "basic": {
      "name": "haji",
      "dob": "2018-01-01",
      "gender": "male",
      "created_at": "2018-01-08T13:38:49.767Z",
      "firstname": "Ah",
      "lastname": "Sh",
      "userType": "Agent",
      "actor": 1,
      "username": "ashu",
      "contact": {
        "email": "ah@gmail.com",
        "phone": 863249517,
        "address": null
      },
      "is_new": false,
      "is_email_verified": true,
      "is_phone_verified": true
    },
    "wallet": {
      "amount": 144.0,
      "tds": 6.0
    },
    "clan": null,
    "balance_lisitings": 48,
    "clan_status": false,
    "listings": [{
      "pid": 36,
      "name": "Labs",
      "website": "Labs",
      "category": {
        "name": "Education"
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 9.52766533190131,
        "lon": 76.8221354484558,
        "state": "Kerala",
        "country": "India",
        "district": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Kottayam"
        },
        "city": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Kanjirappally"
        },
        "place": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Koovappally"
        }
      },
      "package": 0,
      "contact": {
        "email": "ah@gmail.com",
        "phone": 8986234851,
        "address": {
          "country": "India",
          "state": "Kerala",
          "name": "aloh",
          "pincode": 686895,
          "streetAddress": "Kottayam\nKanjirappally",
          "locality": "Koovappally",
          "city": "Koovappally"
        }
      },
      "about": " IT company."
    }, {
      "pid": 37,
      "name": " Louis",
      "website": "ouis",
      "category": {
        "name": "Education"
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 10.0273434437709,
        "lon": 76.5288734436035,
        "state": "Kerala",
        "country": "India",
        "district": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Kottayam"
        },
        "city": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Kanjirappally"
        },
        "place": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Koovappally"
        }
      },
      "package": 0,
      "contact": {
        "email": "soew988@gmail.com",
        "phone": 989756240,
        "address": {
          "country": "India",
          "state": "Kerala",
          "name": "allen45",
          "pincode": 686518,
          "streetAddress": "Sppally",
          "locality": "Koovappally",
          "city": "Koovappally"
        }
      },
      "about": "fsdbgfnvb cvc"
    }],
    "total_listings": 2
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#listings',
  data: {
    data: [],
  },
  mounted() {
    const self = this;

    self.data = e.data;
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="listings" v-if="data.basic">
  <h1>{{data.basic.name}}</h1>
  <h2>{{data.basic.dob}}</h2>
  like wise all data
</div>
```

Comment: sir, how to display email,phone and adsress in basic

Comment: `data.basic.contact.email` because email is inside contact which is inside basic. You may want to read [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-object-syntax/)

Answer (score 1):

Any data nested inside the **data** (and **computed**) property is available in the template between the **{{** and **}}** tags.

For example:

```
Vue.element('my-element', {
    template:
      '<h1>This is an example!</h1>' +
      '<h2>{{ msg }}</h2>'

    data: function () {
      return {
        msg: 'default message'
    }
},
```

So in your case, with nested properties it is exactly the same as you would access them in javascript:

```
Vue.element('my-element', {
    template:
      '<h1>This is an example!</h1>' +
      '<h2>{{ data.wallet.amount }}</h2>'
      '<h2 v-for="listing in listings" :key="listing.pid">{{ listing.name }}</h2>'
    }

    data: function () {
      return {
        data: []
    }
},
```

## **Note**

The data object should be returned from a function, from the original docs:

*When defining a component, data must be declared as a function that returns the initial data object, because there will be many instances created using the same definition. If we use a plain object for data, that same object will be shared by reference across all instances created! By providing a data function, every time a new instance is created we can call it to return a fresh copy of the initial data.* (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)

#### Further reading

I would advise you to read the Vue guide, especially the sections about
[**Declarative Rendering**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering), [**Conditionals and Loops**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Conditionals-and-Loops) and **[Template Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)**

## EDIT

While I was writing my answer, I see you edited your question.

Change your html to this:

```
<div id="listings">
<h1>{{data.basic.name}}</h1>
<h2>{{data.basic.dob}}</h2>
like wise all data
</div>
```

Comment: sir, when is {{data.basic.name}} getting error as [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

(found in <Root>)